# How can I embed google maps into my Python program?

Tags: python, google-maps, tkinter

I'm working on a project in Python using tkinter that will allow for geolocation of IP addresses.  I have the raw conversions down, and I can take an IP address and know city, state, country, longitude, latitude, etc.  I'm wondering if there's any way to embed Google Maps or something similar into my program to offer a visual representation.

Comment: Is this a web or GUI project?

Comment: This is just me, but I'd almost rather prefer you open the link to the map in my browser. I am not a huge fan of those limited functionality maps.

Comment: The whole point is that you have a list of IP addresses on one side of the window, and by clicking on one, the map on the other side of the window will show you where the address is located.  It's not meant to be fully functional (as far as Google Maps is concerned), just for quick reference.

Answer (score 1):

Most GUI Frameworks have a way to embed a web browser frame, with a way to execute javascript from the python code. If this is available to you, you could use the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to display a map.

If you let us know which GUI framework you're using, we might be able to help more.

Comment: to give you an exemple : using PyQt, the `PyQt.QtWebKit` [module](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtwebkit.html) could answer your problem.  

`from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

    # assuming you already have created a window etc..
    self.web = QtWebKit.QWebView()
    self.web.load(QtCore.QUrl(page_url))`

Comment: With PyQt, you can do things like: `self.web.page().currentFrame().evaluateJavaScript("zoomMapOut()")` to change the map from your the rest of your application.

Comment: Tkinter doesn't have a way to easily embed webviews, you could look at PyGtk2Tk, or maybe just use Google's static map api and display a non-interactive image

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need interactivity, the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/) should be simple to integrate into your application. Just build a URL for the map and then download the image and display it.

Note that the [API Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1) have special provisions for non-web-based applications.